# unable to locate package ros-hydro-visp-tracker

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
for some reason I'm unable to install this package, I'm using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-visp-tracker
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-visp-tracker]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-visp-tracker
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-visp-tracker] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140206/unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-visp-tracker/) by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-15**:
What is the error message ? And just in case you misspelled "hydro"

**Comment by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on 2014-03-15**:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-visp-tracker
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-visp-tracker] failed

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-15**:
You should edit your question to add that kind of information. It'll be easier for everyone.

**Comment by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on 2014-03-15**:
thanks, but do you have any idea how to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be due to the migration of the `visp-tracker` package to catkin. Thomas Moulard (author/maintainer) posted to the `ros-release` mailinglist some days ago (from [[1](http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20140313.042119.b999f4c6.html)]):

> Hello,
> could you please add my account: tho..m..@gmail.com to ros-dry-releases?
>
> I would like to remove vision_visp from the repository and release the
> new one through Catkin and Bloom.

It could be that the rosbuild package has been removed, but the catkin package hasn't been released yet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on 2014-03-15**:
I see, thanks.
do you have any idea how to continue with the installation of rosjava (master)? I'm following this tutorial
wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/hydro/Source%20Installation
and I'm getting these errors:
pastebin.com/LV31s8g0
I'm new to the community and I appreciate all the help I can get

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-03-15**:
@AMiNAsFour: this looks like a completely new problem, you should open a new question for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-03-15**:
Also, if you feel this has answered your question, you should mark it answered.